# python decorators to valid user input of different types

Tags: python, class, decorator

I am trying to build a class that has different user inputs. I want to use the decorators that I have written to automatically valid in the initialisation.

The ValidationDecorators is the class that verifies the different types of user input.

```
class ValidationDecorators:
    @staticmethod
    def validate_dataframe(allow_none=False):
        def decorator(fn):
            def wrapper(instance, value):
                if value is None and allow_none:
                    return fn(instance, value)
                if not isinstance(value, pd.DataFrame):
                    raise ValueError("DataFrame must be a pandas DataFrame")
                return fn(instance, value)
            return wrapper
        return decorator

    @staticmethod
    def validate_list(fn):
        def wrapper(instance, value):
            if not isinstance(value, list):
                raise ValueError("List input must be a list of strings")
            if not all(isinstance(col, str) for col in value):
                raise ValueError("List input must contain only strings")
            return fn(instance, value)
        return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    def validate_float(fn):
        def wrapper(instance, value):
            if not isinstance(value, (float, int)) or not (0 < value < 1):
                raise ValueError("Decimal input must be a decimal number between 0 and 1")
            return fn(instance, value)
        return wrapper
```

```
class RandomSampler:
    def __init__(self, original_dataset: pd.DataFrame, target_columns: List[str], sample_size: float = 0.1, sample_dataset: Optional[pd.DataFrame] = None, significance_level: float = 0.05) -> None:
        self._original_dataset = original_dataset
        self._target_columns = target_columns
        self._sample_size = sample_size
        self._sample_dataset  = sample_dataset
        self._significance_level = significance_level
        if self._sample_dataset is None:
            calculated_sample_size = int(len(self._original_dataset) * self._sample_size)
            self._sample_dataset = self._original_dataset.sample(n=calculated_sample_size,random_state=42)
            
    @property
    def original_dataset(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return self._original_dataset

    @original_dataset.setter
    @ValidationDecorators.validate_dataframe(allow_none=False)
    def original_dataset(self, value: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self._original_dataset = value

    @property
    def target_columns(self) -> List[str]:
        return self._target_columns

    @target_columns.setter
    @ValidationDecorators.validate_list
    def target_columns(self, value: List[str]) -> None:
        for col in value:
            if col not in self._original_dataset.columns:
                raise KeyError(f"Column '{col}' does not exist in the original dataset")
        self._target_columns = value

    @property
    def sample_size(self) -> float:
        return self._sample_size

    @sample_size.setter
    @ValidationDecorators.validate_float
    def sample_size(self, value: float) -> None:
        self._sample_size = value

    @property
    def sample_dataset(self) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:
        return self._sample_dataset

    @sample_dataset.setter
    @ValidationDecorators.validate_dataframe(allow_none=True)
    def sample_dataset(self, value: Optional[pd.DataFrame]) -> None:
        self._sample_dataset = value

    @property
    def significance_level(self):
        return self._significance_level
    
    @significance_level.setter
    @ValidationDecorators.validate_float
    def significance_level(self, value):
        self._significance_level = value
```

This should throw an error as sample_size is not a valid input. However, it doesn't do that.

```
client = RandomSampler(full_data,['AGE'],sample_dataset=sample_data, sample_size=100)
```

However, when I do the following it works fine.

```
client = RandomSampler(full_data,['AGE'],sample_dataset=sample_data, sample_size=100)
client.sample_size = 100
```

```
    raise ValueError("Decimal input must be a decimal number between 0 and 1")
ValueError: Decimal input must be a decimal number between 0 and 1
```

I want all the user inputs to be validates using the relevant ValidationDecorators to run checks during the **init**. Can you please suggest what would be the best way to do this or any better alternate approaches?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`pydantic`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The way you have things set up, the decorators only activate when you change the "public" non-underscored attributes. That's why it works here:

```
client.sample_size = 100
```

But in your `__init__` function, the "private" underscored variable is changed, thereby circumventing your decorators:

```
self._sample_size = sample_size
```

You should change the above line to:

```
self.sample_size = sample_size
```

and then it will perform the check. Same goes for the rest of them.

Comment: I changed all the variables as per your instructions. However, I get a long as error which goes in like a loop. Below is piece of the error:
`self.original_dataset = value
  File "c:\Users\D\OneDrive\packages.py", line 15, in wrapper       
    return fn(instance, value)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: I didn't mean change *ALL* the variables, only the ones in your `__init__`, as changing all of them would result in the error you described. Frankly you should just read more about how properties work. . .

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any references or website that I can read more about properties?